# loading data into delta lake from azure blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, delta-lake

I am trying to load data into delta lake from azure blob storage.
I am using below code snippet

storage_account_name = "xxxxxxxxdev"
storage_account_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

file_location = "wasbs://bicc-hdspk-eus-qc@xxxxxxxxdev.blob.core.windows.net/FSHC/DIM/FSHC_DIM_SBU"

file_type = "csv"

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",storage_account_access_key)

df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", '|').load(file_location)

dx = df.write.format("parquet")

### Till this step it is working and I am also able to load it into databricks table.

dx.write.format("delta").save(file_location)

error : AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'write'

p.s. - Am I passing the file location wrong into the write statement? If this is the cause then what is file path for delta lake.

Please revert to me in case additional information is needed.

Thanks,
Abhirup

Answer (score 2):

dx is a dataframewriter, so what youre trying to do doesnt make sense.  You could do this:

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type).option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", '|').load(file_location)

df.write.format("parquet").save()
df.write.format("delta").save()
```

Comment: Thanks..I also realized the same mistake later. Now the issue is resolved.